# How can I extend ActiveRecord model with new propery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm developing a REST API and before send results (fetched from DB with ACtiveRecord) to client I need to extend it with some additional data. Here is how I suppose it to be:

```
  def index
    (categories = Category.all()).each() do |category|
      category.image = "some image"
    end
    render json: categories
  end
```

It seems like Ruby does not add object proporties on the fly, like JS would do, so this code ends up with error message

```
undefined method `image=' for #<Category:0x007f89f0513d40>
```

I read a lot and found solution to add `attr_accessor :image` in my `Category` model. Now it does not throw error but also `image` property does not appeared in JSON output.

Comment: add this like to category.rb after the class definition: `attr_accesor :image`

Comment: @Octopus-Paul as I noticed in original post, after adding `attr_accesor :image` in my model I still getting output without `image` property in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) method with `attr_accessor :image` in category model.

```
def index
  categories = Category.all.each do |category|
    category.image = 'some image'
  end
  render json: categories.as_json(methods: :image)
end
```

In rails < 4.2 it has different name - [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

Comment: it seems like instead of `attr_reader` it should be `attr_accessor`

Comment: This is presentation problem and better solution is to use jbuilder gem for that as @mohammad-abushady suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of playing with the object it self, you might want to take a few mins and learn how jbuilder works, it's very simple and it would make your life a lot easier, especially when the json format includes a little extra/different data from your original database object,
Here's a simple format of what you might do

```
# app/views/categories/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @categories do |category|
  json.prop1 category.prop1
  json.prop2 category.prop2
  json.image whatever_image_function_here
end
```

Other solution would be overriding the `as_json` method of the class